# My domain and web services

Tags: webservices, mydomain

sorry if this is a stupid question but I am a bit newie with Salesforce.

My client would like to enable My Domain feature. We have some web services deployed and working in production. The url endpoints for this web services are like https://euXX.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/web_service_name.

My question is, if after activate My Domain, do we have to change the url endpoints of these webservices to the new domain url like: https://mydomain.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/web_service_name ?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

I have tested in a sandbox, I am able to get the access_token using both endpoints (csXXX.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?... and mydomain.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?...) but when I call the webservice using endpoint csXXX.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/wservicename. i get "errorCode": "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED","message": "HTTP Method 'GET' not allowed. Allowed are POST" (the method is setted in POST but i get that message). If I call the webservice using mydomain.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/wservicename, the webservice responds ok...

Answer (score 0):

You still should be able to reach sf with the current url's.
As long as you don't deactivate.
[image]

To confirm I just logged in with https://csXXX.salesforce.com

Comment: Are you sure about that? I have tested in a sandbox and I am able to get the access_token using both endpoints (https://csXXX.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?... and https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?...) but when I call the webservice using endpoint euXX.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/wservicename. i get "errorCode": "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED","message": "HTTP Method 'GET' not allowed. Allowed are POST" (the method is setted in POST but i get that message). If I call the webservice using endpoint with mydomain, the webservice responds ok